# 2 singly linked list intersection

Tags: python, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to create 2 single linked lists and find the intersection between them.  I'm getting errors such as NameError: obj is not defined for the LinkedList line and would like a working solution.  How do I make this work?  What am I doing wrong?  Am I even close?  What is the meaning of life?  This is in python.

```
class IntersectSolution:
    def intersect(sll_a, sll_b):
        b_x_node = sll_b
        while sll_b and not sll_a.search(sll_b.get_data()):
            sll_b.get_next()
            b_x_node = sll_b
        if b_x_node == None:
            print("No intersections between nodes.")
        print("Intersection node is: {}".format(b_x_node))

class Node:
    def __init__(self, data = None, next_node = None):
        self.data = data
        self.next_node = next_node

    def get_data(self):
        return self.data

    def get_next(self):
        return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, new_node):
        self.next_node = new_node

class LinkedList(obj):
    def __init__(self, head = None):
        self.head = head

    def insert(self, data):
        new_node = Node(data)
        new_node.set_next(self.head)
        self.head = new_node

    def size(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.get_next
        return count

    def search(self, data):
        current = self.head
        found = False
        while current and found is False:
            if current.get_data() == data:
                found = True
            else:
                current = current.get_next()
        if current is None:
            raise ValueError("Data not in list")
        return current

    def delete(self, data):
        current = self.head
        previous = None
        found = False
        while current and found is False:
            if current.get_data() == data:
                found = True
            else:
                previous = current
                current = current.get_next()
        if current is None:
            raise ValueError("Data not in list")
        if previous is None:
            self.head = current.get_next()
        else:
            previous.set_next(current.get_next())

a = LinkedList(Node)
b = LinkedList(Node)
for i in range(1, 15, 2):
    a.insert(i)
for j in range(23, 8, -3):
    b.insert(j)

ISoln = IntersectSolution
ISoln.intersect(a,b)
```

Comment: getting this error as well in my for loop initialization of a and b - insert() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'... I dropped the obj parameters; therefore removing Node parameter in LinkedList and it moved further along.

Comment: getting this error at insert inside the LinkedList class - AttributeError: type object 'LinkedList' has no attribute 'head'...  Shouldn't the __init___ cover this problem and give it this attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate both linked-lists by implementing a custom `__add__` method and then finding the values in the concatenated result that exist in both original lists:

```
class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self, _val=None):
     self.val = _val
     self._next = None
   def insert(self, _val):
     if self.val is None:
       self.val = _val
     else:
       getattr(self._next, 'insert', lambda x:setattr(self, '_next', LinkedList(x)))(_val)
   def __iter__(self): #iterate over all values in list
      yield self.val
      yield from [[], self._next][bool(self._next)]
   def __add__(self, _list): #concatenate two linkedlists
      _l = self.__class__()
      for i in _list:
         _l.insert(i)
      for i in self:
         _l.insert(i)
      return _l
   def __contains__(self, _val): #check if a value exists in the list
      if self.val is None:
        return False
      return True if self.val == _val else getattr(self._next, '__contains__', lambda _:False)(_val)
   @classmethod
   def intersection(cls, _a, _b):
     _result = cls()
     for i in (_a+_b):
       if i in _a and i in _b and i not in _result:
         _result.insert(i)
     return _result
```

---

```
l = LinkedList()
for i in range(10):
  l.insert(i)

l1 = LinkedList() 
for i in range(6, 14):
  l1.insert(i)

_intersection = LinkedList.intersection(l, l1)
print([i for i in _intersection])
```

Output:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Worked for me, don't fret.

Comment: @RyanWolfe9013 Glad to help!

Comment: One question, this all makes sense to me except one part... 
yield from [[], self._next][bool(self._next)]
what does this line do?  I'm guessing this is the actual iterator through the list but it isn't clicking with the from and square brackets inside one of the double square brackets.  Is there a way you can explain it's function to me?

Comment: @RyanWolfe9013 That line calls `__iter__` on the reference to the next node in the list. However, if the end of the list has been reached, `self._next` will be `None`, whose truthy value is `False`. Thus, it will iterate over the empty list, and not continue the recursion.

Comment: Nvm, one more question... self.__class__(), what does this do when you assign it to _l.  I specifically don't know __class__() function; does that create a class?

Comment: @RyanWolfe9013 That is correct. `self.__class__` is a reference to the class object itself, `LinkedList`. `self.__class__()` is the same as `LinkedList()`.